# iOS - How to use synchronous requests with loading indicator

Tags: ios, asynchronous, loading

So I am trying to display an animated loading view (custom built) that will continue to animate while making a synchronous request to a web service.
I am familiar with synchronous and asynchrous requests using NSURLConnections and delegates, but my problem is that I want to ensure that my thread WAITS for the request to finish BUT still animates my loading indicator.

Are there any suggestions as to what the best way to go about this is?

Comment: Why does the request need to be synchronous? It sounds like you can accomplish what you want by running it asynchronously and then removes the loading indicator once it completes, maybe in a callback. I recommend checking out AFNetworking https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking

Comment: You can still wait for completion if you are using an asynchronous call. You shouldn't be using synchronous calls on the main thread no matter what.

Comment: How can I wait for completion if the asynchronous request is called from a seperate class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing this with a synchronous request is not the way to go -- if you want your app to "wait" for the request to finish, you just put whatever code you want to resume after the request finishes in the connectionDidFinishLoading: method. That way, your UI will not be stalled and you can animate your loading indicator.

Comment: Ok so here is the situation: I have a shared player object that contains all the player data. There are times when I want to show a new view, but FIRST I need to download the data from the network and update it onto the device. Since I have the methods set in the Player Class to do this, I can't always call my actions in connectionDidFinishLoading (i.e. performSegue). Does that clarify a bit more of what I am trying to accomplish?

Comment: Is connectionDidFinishLoading in another class?  If so you can either use notifications or a delegate protocol to notify your Player class when the download finishes.

Comment: Ahhh so dumb of me. I ended up using notifications, just recently became familiar with using them and completely forgot they can be accessed across different classes so easily. Thanks!